# How to call javascript function from Observer file in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, javascript, event-observer, jquery

I have created a custom js file in my custom module.

**app\code\Vendor\Module\view\frontend\layout\default.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<head>
     <script src="Vendor_Module::js/test.js"/>
 </head>
```

**app\code\Vendor\Module\view\frontend\web\js\test.js**

```
function Test(json){
 console.log('Test Web',json);
}
```

Then used add to cart event.

**app\code\Vednor\Module\etc\events.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
  <event name="checkout_cart_product_add_after">
    <observer name="vendor_module_observer_checkoutcartproductaddafter" 
      instance="Vendor\Module\Observer\Checkoutcartproductaddafter" />
  </event>
 </config>
```

**Vendor\Module\Observer\Checkoutcartproductaddafter.php**

```
class Checkoutcartproductaddafter implements \Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface
{

private $image;
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Catalog\Helper\Image $image
{
    $this->image = $image;
}

public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
{
    $event = $observer->getEvent();

    $eventData = $event->getData('quote_item');
    $item = ($eventData->getParentItem() ? $eventData->getParentItem() : $eventData);
    $product = $item->getProduct();
    $productId = $product->getId();
    $imageHelper = $this->image;
    $productImageUrl = $imageHelper->init($product, 'product_page_image_large')->getUrl();
    $OrgPrice = (float)$product->getPrice();

    $prepareJson = array(
            'event_name' => 'Added To Cart',
            'event_data' => array(
                'productId' => $productId,
                'productName' => $product->getName(),
                'productDescription' => $product->getDescription(),
                'productShortDescription' => $product->getShortDescription(),
                'productSku' => $product->getSku(),
                'productUrl' => $product->getProductUrl(),
                'productImage' => $productImageUrl,
                'productOriginalPrice' => $OrgPrice,
                'productQty' => (float)$eventData->getQty(),
        )
    );

    $json = json_encode($prepareJson);
    echo '<script type="text/javascript">
            require(["jquery", "jquery/ui"], function($){ 
            $(document).ready(function(){
                console.log("inside observer");
                Test('.$json.')
            });
         });</script>';
    return $this;
    }
 }
```

So whenever Add to cart is happened, I am trying to call my js function. but which is not happening.

Same I have to achieve for all the main events in magento. so created the common js function and trying to send the data in each observers.

In the above example i have mentioned Add to cart event to see if that works.

Can anyone help me with this. Thanks!!

Comment: maybe this can guide you a little to achieve the same. https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/239524/51548

Comment: @RizwanKhan, I am trying to implement it for all the major events, so the link you shared may work for Add to cart. so instead of writing the mixins for each events, can we do it via observer? Any chances there]

Comment: @RizwanKhan, if any other approach is there, pls suggest me

Comment: There are various ways that the backend and fronted are kept in sync. The details depend on the implementation. E.g. customerData can manage data in the browser's local storage, and that is how, e.g., the minicart is updated asynchronously, using knockout subscribers. You could use that *model* for additional features, but they will require a specific approach to each event that hooks in to how the event is triggered in the browser and handled in the backend.

Comment: @jiheison, please update me as answer how this can be achieved.

Comment: How customerData works is detailed here: https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/143381/66951 . Basically, you   would hook a custom customerData "section" to your event's action (e.g. adding an item to the cart), and then trigger the customerData reload either when the page reloads or an AJAX query completes. When the customerData reload completes the knockout subscriber triggers your custom JS. No backend observer is required, because your sections.xml will trigger the backend action based on the request path.

Answer (score 0):

I would do this way:

In your observer add the data to session.

```
use Magento\Customer\Model\Session
$this->customerSession->setMyData($json)
```

And in my `default.xml`

```
    <referenceContainer name="before.body.end">
        <block class="NameSpace\ModuleName\View\Element\Template" name="my.before.end" template="NameSpace_ModuleName::before-body-end.phtml" />
    </referenceContainer>
```

And now in `NameSpace\ModuleName\View\Element\Template.php` class:

```
public function getJsonDataFromSession()
{
    //Magento\Customer\Model\Session
    return $this->customerSession->getMyData();
}
```

and in `before-body-end.phtml`

```
<?php $jsonData = $this->getJsonDataFromSession()?>
<?php if ($jsonData):?>
    //call your script
<?php endif;?>
```

**Important**

Have some logic to clear your session data to handle browser refresh or something similar.

Not tested but should work. Good luck.

**UPDATE**

When a product is added to the cart the local storage information is updated and you can subscribe to a knockout observable.

```
require(['Magento_Customer/js/customer-data'], function (customerData) {
    var cart = customerData.get('cart');
    var count = cart().summary_count;
    cart.subscribe(function () {
        if (cart().summary_count !== count) {
            count = cart().summary_count;
            // call your code here
            console.log('Number of items in cart is now: ' + count);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: how to clear the session. if page refreshed. any way to handle it?

Comment: also this is not working for add to cart, my function is not being called

Comment: session data will get only when page is refreshed, not upon add to cart, because that's a ajax call.

Comment: You can use `knockout`.

Comment: possible to update as answer pls?  @Adarsh.

Comment: Check my update.

Comment: so now observer implementation is not required?

Comment: As long as you depend upon the `Magento_Customer/js/customer-data` you don't need observer implementation.

Comment: if this approach is used then, we need to write this for all other events in individual pages?